# How to set condition for div id

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, joomla2.5

I am trying to pass condition for id ? How to achieve the below condition

```
if ( $vm->check( "pagetype = cart" ) )
{
echo $ showRightcolumn? 'contentarea2' : 'newcontentarea';
}
else
echo $showRightColumn ? 'contentarea2' : 'contentarea';
```

in this statement

```
<div id="<?php echo $showRightColumn ? 'contentarea2' : 'contentarea'; ?>">
```

Comment: have you tried shorthand if statement ? [Check it here](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any complex processing you could always create a function to return the ID that you want to return, and then echo the result of the function, something like:

```
<?php
  function getId($vm, $showRightColumn) {
    if ($vm->check("pagetype = cart")) {
      return $showRightcolumn ? 'contentarea2' : 'newcontentarea';
    }
    return $showRightColumn ? 'contentarea2' : 'contentarea';
  }
?>
<div id="<?php echo getId($vm, $showRightColumn); ?>">...</div>
```

However, for simpler conditionals, it may just be better to use a ternary operator which evaluates other ternary statements (as suggested by other answers).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
<div id="<?php echo $vm->check( "pagetype = cart" ) 
                    ? ($showRightColumn ? 'contentarea2' : 'newcontentarea') 
                    : ($showRightColumn ? 'contentarea2' : 'contentarea') ; 
         ?>"
>
```

Comment: @Waqas Khan: Updated. There is double understanding in your code : how is spelled `$showRightColumn` or `$showRightcolumn`?